# How to get metadata object from retrieveSetupIntent?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using the client side `retrieveSetupIntent` call to get a setupIntent, but the `metadata` object is undefined.

```
const { setupIntent, error } = await stripe.retrieveSetupIntent(setupClientSecret);
console.log('metadata :', setupIntent.metadata); // This doesn't work, no metadata
```

However, in the `setup_intent.succeeded` webhook the metadata object is present, just not when using this client side call.

Does anyone know if/how this can be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metadata can contain sensitive information and are only returned when using a Secret API key server-side. Client-side, you use a Publishable API key and the `metadata` hash is never returned.

Comment: But I do have a client secret that’s returned to me and I’m using that to retrieve the setupIntent?

Comment: That doesn't change the answer. It's still happening client-side and Stripe won't return sensitive information like `metadata` or `charges`. You get a limited version of the PaymentIntent client-side in that case.